# Shorthand CSS on html emails possible?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am wondering if shorthand CSS coding is allowed for HTML Emails.

I know the CSS allowed is very limited but I know padding for example is allowed but would this be allowed:

```
padding:0 4px 0 6px;
```

Comment: Test it for yourself.

Comment: And consider all the major email clients - including webmail clients like Gmail, Hotmail... They all have different rules for processing HTML emails

Comment: You can find online guides, like [Campaign Monitor's CSS for email clients](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). "Just trying it out" is a very time consuming and cumbersome process.

Comment: @JoelGlovier When asking for free help, users are encouraged to at least put in the very basic minimum prior effort first. That does not only result in a better set of curated Q&A for future visitors  (notice how this question has attracted only 2,000 viewers in _eight years_) but is just generally a polite thing to do. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

And, as with any "webpage", what the user actually sees is completely up to the "browser" (or HTML-capable email client).

You could have simply tried it to find out.

<sub>Also, I recommend [not being obnoxious](http://www.georgedillon.com/web/html_email_is_evil.shtml) by splashing graphics and colours all over emails. :(</sub>

Comment: Fyi. the link you posted is at least 5 years old. (looking at the bottom it says `[Updated - 19 March 2006]`

Comment: @ITroubs: And? So? Therefore?

Answer (score 5):

The CSS that is allowed in an email is what the receiving email client understands. There are many different email clients. Not all of them even render HTML email (though virtually all do these days), but even where they do render HTML, their rendering engines will all be different from one another, in the same way as web browsers. But unlike web browsers, people don't always change their email client if they're not happy with the way it renders.

So you should expect your email to be read using virtually any kind of email program, including ones which don't render HTML at all, and those which render it, but using an IE4-vintage rendering engine.

That said, I would expect virtually all email clients to correctly interpret the CSS `padding` style.

You may get some with quirks-mode box models, which will cause your box sizes and positions to be wrong, but they should still interpret the `padding` correctly within their own set of rules.

One thing I would say is that you should ensure all your CSS code is embedded in the HTML. Put a big `<style>` tag at the top of your document, rather than a `<link>` tag with an external reference. The reason for this is that 1) some users may view your email when they're offline, in which case they won't be able to load an external stylesheet, and 2) some email clients may be set to block loading external files from within an email for security reasons, even if the user is online. If your styles are all included in the main body of the email, this won't be a problem. (you may still have the same issue with graphics, but that's a whole different topic of discussion)

Comment: `That said, I would expect virtually all email clients to correctly interpret the CSS padding style.` Nope. Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 do not support padding on `p` elements or `div` elements. [Source](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Answer (score 2):

I have never had a problem doing 'shorthand' like that, so long as *all* of the values are provided.
Technically, `padding:0px 4px;` should work such that top & bottom are 0, and left & right are 4, but not all email clients will honor that (I'm talking to you, Outlook 2007/2010!) so you need to include all four for margin, padding, border etc.

Answer (score 2):

In case this is still of interest I have been looking into this lately. Some mass mail company clearly state that some applications like font (at least) are not rendered well on some email clients.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/

Actually after reviewing a few email sources of templates (Mailchimp, Campaign Monitor, etc) they all consistently avoid them so my conclusion so far is been to do so as well.

In any case more important than shorthand or not is the fact that most CSS styles need to get "inline" of elements as many (Gmail included) ignores them if defined on the head.

As a simple solution I tend to use basic styles on the body element and on a containing table surrounding the content (as body styles also get removed by some clients).

Comment: Gmail now seems to also handle CSS styles defined in the head tag, but other webmail providers still don't.

Answer (score 1):

In a simplest form you can set styling for each element like this:

```
<p style="padding:0 4px 0 6px;">your contents</p>
```